# Hide dropdown in search select when search content is null in antd

Tags: css, reactjs, select, antd, show-hide

Here is my code:

```
<Select
  showSearch
  allowClear
  listHeight={160}
  placeholder="Customer's name"
  optionFilterProp="children"
  style={{ minWidth: '170px', marginRight: '4px' }}
  onChange={onChangeCustomer}
  onSearch={onSearchCustomer}
  filterOption={(input, option) =>
    (option?.label ?? '').toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
  }
  options={listCustomers}
/>;
```

I don't know how to solve this problem
I hope I will solve this problem in the future

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to provide a [complete and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but also keep it minimal and only include code that's necessary for reproducing the problem

Comment: Please provide more detail and code related search.